# Changing the syntax colors for Firebug?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I know you can edit the syntax colors in the Chrome Web Inspector by editing the user css file, but is there a way to do this for Firebug? I'm using 1.12.5 on FF 27 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an additional `UI` plugin. Here is what I utilize:

#### https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/acebug/

It supports importing `themes`, which can modify the coloring and styling of the markup.

**EDIT**

Another way would be to change the CSS using Stylish. How this is done is [described in Jan Odvarko's blog](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/firebug-tip-alternative-firebug-themes/).

Comment: apparently only on the command line and large html/css editors.  Not the document inspector.